# What is the difference between "a is b" and "id(a) == id(b)" in Python?

Tags: python, identity

The [`id()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id) inbuilt function gives...

> an integer (or long integer) which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime.

The [`is`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) operator, instead, gives...

> object identity

So why is it possible to have two objects that have the same `id` but return `False` to an `is` check?  Here is an example:

```
>>> class Test():
...   def test():
...     pass
>>> a = Test()
>>> b = Test()
>>> id(a.test) == id(b.test)
True
>>> a.test is b.test
False
```

A more troubling example: (continuing the above)

```
>>> b = a
>>> b is a
True
>>> b.test is a.test
False
>>> a.test is a.test
False
```

However:

```
>>> new_improved_test_method = lambda: None
>>> a.test = new_improved_test_method
>>> a.test is a.test
True
```

Comment: It's not like I _need_ this for an actual program or metaclass jedi mind trick, mind you. I was bored on the train and I tried that :)

Comment: I think the important question is why `a.test is a.test` is False. Once you know that the rest should make sense...

Comment: The oil spill is fine and dandy and it's coming to a city near you Real Soon! Maybe you should organize some get together to celebrate its coming!

Comment: == and is are completely independent. Here's a case where is does not imply equality. `a = float('nan'); print a is a, a == a`

Comment: @Paul: I didn't ask about `a == b`, I asked about `id(a) == id(b)` :)

Comment: Related (not duplicate): *[Why does comparing strings using either '==' or 'is' sometimes produce a different result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce-a-differe)*

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
>>> b.test is a.test
False
>>> a.test is a.test
False
```

Methods are created on-the-fly each time you look them up. The function object (which is always the same object) implements the [descriptor protocol](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/) and its `__get__` creates the bound method object. No two bound methods would normally be the same object.

```
>>> id(a.test) == id(b.test)
True
>>> a.test is b.test
False
```

This example is deceptive. The result of the first is only `True` by coincidence. `a.test` creates a bound method and it's garbage collected after computing `id(a.test)` because there aren't any references to it. (Note that you quote the documentation saying that an id is "unique and constant for this object *during its lifetime*" (emphasis mine).) `b.test` *happens* to have the same id as the bound method you had before and it's allowed to because no other objects have the same id now.

Note that you should seldom use `is` and even less often use `id`. `id(foo) == id(bar)` is always wrong.

---

Regarding your new example, hopefully you get what it does now:

```
>>> new_improved_test_method = lambda: None
>>> a.test = new_improved_test_method
>>> a.test is a.test
True
```

In this case, we aren't making methods on the fly from functions on the class automatically binding self and returning bound method objects. In this case, you simply store a function as an instance attribute. Nothing special happens on lookup (descriptors only get called when you look up a class attribute), so every time you look up the attribute, you get the original object you stored.

Comment: *"Methods are created on-the-fly each time you look them up. The function object (which is always the same object) implements the descriptor protocol and its `__get__` creates the bound method object. No two bound methods would normally be the same object."*  Ha, that's news to me.  Nice!