# Python 'is not' operator

Tags: python

I notice there is a comparison operator `is not`. Should I literally translate it into

```
!=
```

instead of

```
== not
```

?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#notin

Comment: The link in the venerable Ignatio's comment is broken, it should read: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#not-in (added a hyphen in the anchor)

Comment: I think it should be https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is-not

Comment: Related (could be closer to the intended for some search engine queries): *[Python != operation vs "is not"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209755/python-operation-vs-is-not)*. Which is a duplicate of *[Why does comparing strings using either '==' or 'is' sometimes produce a different result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce-a-differe)*

Answer (score 72, accepted):

To expand on what [Ignacio said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485180/python-is-not-operator/4485205#4485205):

`a == b` and `a != b` test whether two objects have the same *value*. You can override an object's `__eq__` and `__ne__` methods to determine what that means.

`a is b` and `a is not b` test whether two objects are the same thing. It's like doing `id(a) == id(b)`.

Comment: except without the race condition

Comment: @Lie Ryan: Care to elaborate? I don't know about that.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906177/what-is-the-difference-between-a-is-b-and-ida-idb-in-python, especially Mike Graham's answer about `id(a.test) == id(b.test)` and `a.test is b.test`; to paraphrase, `id(a) == id(b)` does not guarantee that `a` and `b` are still alive when the comparison is made, and could cause some surprises when `a` is garbage collected before the comparison and `b` is created just then.

Comment: Interesting to be reminded that this breaks my normal mental rule of thumb that "not X" has a higher precedence than everything else. It is parsed as "A (is not) B" instead, where "is not" is an atomic operator.

Comment: You say "whether two objects are the same thing". What is that thing?

Comment: @JonathanHartley `a is not b` cannot be parsed as `a is (not b)` because the `is` operator has a higher precedence than the `not` operator in python. So the only possible way to parse it is as `is not`. That's also why `a == not b` is a syntax error and `not a == b` is parsed as `not (a == b)`.

Answer (score 21):

It's not a relational comparison; it's identity. And it translates to `not (A is B)`.

Answer (score 7):

[Python 2.7.3 documentation, 5.9. Comparisons](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html):

> The operators <, >, ==, >=, <=, and != compare the values of two objects.

and about operator **is** in the same chapter:

> The operators is and is not test for object identity: x is y is true if and only if x and y are the same object. x is not y yields the inverse truth value.

Answer (score 1):

```
A != B
```

means that "A *is not equal to* B", not "A *is equal to not* B".

Comment: What's the difference?  If A is not equal to B,  A would have to be equal to *something* let's assume A equals C.  That means C does not equal B.  Therefore, A is equal to not B(C).

Comment: @John: "A is equal to C", "A is not equal to B", and "C is not equal to B" does not imply that "(not(B)) is equal to C"; it is a faulty reasoning to conclude from this that "A is equal to not B".

Comment: This comment is based on a misunderstanding of the question. "A is not B" is not parsed as "A is (not B)". It is parsed as "A (is not) B", where "is not" is an operator that tests for "not (A is B)".

Comment: @John : For (A,B)=(2,0), "A is not equal to B" is True but "A is equal to not B" is False. So A != B is definitely not the same as A == (not B).