# Python "is not True" same as "is False"?

Tags: python, logical-operators

I am curious about the precedence of "x is not True" in Python. At first, I assume it means "!= True", but then I though the "not True" is surely of higher precedence that "is not". Yet the following seems to indicate the latter:

```
>>> 4 is not True    
True    
>>> not True    
False     
>>> 4 is False     
False     
>>> 4 is (not True)
False
```

It seems Python interprets "is not True" as a single expression, rather than "is (not True)" which is equivalent to "is False".

I am not new to Python programming, yet I have not thought deeply about this before. Can I safely assume that "is not" is an operator in itself that has higher parsing precedence that "not True"?

Comment: "Is not" is indeed an operator in itself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485180/python-is-not-operator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it isn't. `x is not True` will be true for *any value `x` that is not the singleton object `True`*

> It seems Python interprets "is not True" as a single expression,
>   rather than "is (not True)" which is equivalent to "is False".

Precisely. You can actually see this in the disassembled bytecode, `is not` is its own comparison operation

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis("x is not True")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (True)
              4 COMPARE_OP               9 (is not)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

`is not` is an operator, the opposite of `is`.

```
x is not y
```

means

```
not (x is y)
```

It does *not* mean

```
x is (not y)
```

---

E.g.

```
4 is not False
```

is **True** (it means `not (4 is False)`)

whereas

```
4 is (not False)
```

is **False** (since `not False` evaluates to `True`, not the value `4`).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in python, `is not` is an operator of its own, not a composition of `is` and `not`. And the `is not` operator has a higher precedence than the `not` operator. If you want, you can check this in [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is-not)

Answer (score 1):

4 (is not) `True` (The `bool`), Because 4 is 4 (The int).