# Is there a way to avoid the overhead of nested functions in Python, whilst keeping the structure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

I find that that nesting functions can make code more readable, and manageable, just like indenting can. However, there is a performance impact due to the reloading each nested function each time the outer function is called (see these Q's on Stack Overflow
[What is the performance overhead of nested functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14055843/what-is-the-performance-overhead-of-nested-functions?lq=1)
[Is there an overhead when nesting functions in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839632/is-there-an-overhead-when-nesting-functions-in-python)).

Would it be possible to avoid this overhead by using a decorator or some other trick to avoid the issue?

Comment: Unless you have done some profiling that proves otherwise, this is a premature optimization (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385506/when-is-optimisation-premature) you should not worry about. The time it takes to define a function is neglectable, especially when compared to the benefits it provides (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241523/why-does-python-code-run-faster-in-a-function)

Comment: You can't use a decorator (on the inner function) to do what you want, because they are executed _after_ the function has been defined. A decorator on the outer function _could_ technically work, but it would really be overkill.

Comment: Just define those functions at the top-level instead... no need to nest them if you don't need a closure.

Comment: The nested functions must be bound to the variables in the outer function that they use. How should that be achieved without any kind of overhead?